# Split a String into Multiple Strings (When a certain character occurs)

Tags: java, string, parsing

I need to write a method that takes a String and separates the String into a String[] every time there is a `;`. For example, if I give it `test;test2;test 3`, it should give me a String[] containing `test`, `test2`, and `test 3`

EDIT: Sorry guys, I just blanked out. Mods, feel free to delete it.

Comment: Have you checked the [String javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) and looked for a `split` method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`String.split()` is your friend and answer.

`"test;test2;test 3".split(";")` will return an array consisting of Strings `"test", "test2", "test 3"`.

Comment: -_- total blank out. I use split() all the time but I usually give it a " " parameter so I forgot. Thanks.

Comment: I have an impression that this question shows up at least once per day on SO, so no biggie :)

Answer (score 1):

Try myVarString.split(";") method

Answer (score 0):

```
String s="test;test1;test;2";
String [] array= s.split(";");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var str = "Test1;Test2; Test 3";

str = str.split(";");
```

Here is a [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/SchmalzyB/DRKeA/)